# Ruby on rails Case when statement not working

Tags: ruby

I can't understand why my case/when statement is not working... i couldn't find much information about 'AND (&&)' operator.

```
points = -180
case points
 when (points >= -9999) && (points < -300) then
    title = "bad player"
 when (points >= -300) && (points < -100) then
    title = "not reliable"
 when (points >= -100) && (points < 100) then
    title = "Newbie"
end
```

I'm getting title = blank..

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
points = -180
case
when (points >= -9999) && (points < -300)
  title = "bad player"
when (points >= -300) && (points < -100)
  title = "not reliable"
when (points >= -100) && (points < 100)
  title = "Newbie"
end

#=> "not reliable"
```

You can also use range

```
points = -180

title = 
  case points
  when -9999..-301
    "bad player"
  when -300..-99
    "not reliable"
  when -100..99
    "Newbie"
  end


#=> "not reliable"
```

Comment: Worked. Cheers!

Comment: Glad that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

So you are `case`-ing on the `points` variable, but you try to do something completely different in the `when` clauses. At least two of the three `when`s will evaluate to `false`, the other one - possibly to `true`. So you are actually checking if `-180` is `true` or `false`.

---

What you actually wanted to do was probably:

```
case points
when -9999...-300 then 'bad player'
when -300...-100  then 'not reliable'
when -100...100   then 'Newbie'
end
```